# Working with CodeIgniter routes?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think this is a route issue but I'm not sure. I have a page with this URL:

> siteurl.com/kowmanger/titles/titles/edit/$id

I'm trying to find out that when I'm on this page I load the titles page it says page not found so I need to tell it that the `$id` is just a paramter so I can use it to get the data of the title.

**UPDATE :**

So I decided to change my titles controller so that there's a edit and add function inside of the titles controller that way they dont' have separate controllers when they are in fact methods.

So now I have:

> kansasoutalwwrestling.com/kowmanager/titles/titles - list of titles
>
> kansasoutalwwrestling.com/kowmanager/titles/titles/add - addnew form
>
> kansasoutalwwrestling.com/kowmanager/titles/titles/edit/$id - edit form

I don't have any routes set up so far for this. For some reason though I"m getting the same page for both of these page.

> kansasoutalwwrestling.com/kowmanager/titles/titles/add - addnew form
> (right link url) kansasoutalwwrestling.com/kowmanager/titles/add -
> addnew form

I need a route so that it'll show the correct url if the add method is accessed.

Also I need to set up a route so that if the correct edit link is accessed it sees the id attached to the end of the url and it'll accept it so that I can do a my database query to get the title data.

UPDATE: So to reiterate I have a module(subfolder) called titles. Inside of the module I have a controller called titles and inside of that controller I have 3 functions called index(), add(), edit().

I tried using Chris's suggestion on the routes but its not routing correctly. Also wanted to mention I'm using wiredesignz modular separation framework if that matters.

Any additional ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the correct URL? `titles/titles` doesn't make any sense to me. Perhaps it should've been like `kowmanger/titles/edit/id` instead.

Comment: I'm sure because titles was the module and titles is the controller

Comment: What do your routes look like now? To what controller action do you want this URL to correspond?

Comment: Please could you clarify whether you get the `page not found` error when you try to access the URL you've posted, or whether you're on that page and you get the error when you try to "load the titles page" from that page?

Comment: yeah this is all inside of my project that requires a login

Comment: Also, if I go to `http://siteurl.com/kowmanger/` I get a `page not found` error, but if I go to `http://siteurl.com/` then it returns a valid page. Assuming that siteurl.com is the actual domain name and you're not using it as a placeholder (like example.com) then it seems that there may be a more fundamental problem with your area of the site. Could you confirm that siteurl.com is the actual domain name?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file with rewrite rules that allow you to omit index.php in your URL's? Could you answer my earlier question?

Comment: I'm still not clear on when the `page not found` error is occurring. Does it happen when you try to access the URL you've posted, or when you try to access some other URL from that page?

Comment: When I go to http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/titles/edit/1 it says page not found.

Comment: Whats the route your actually using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible answer based on your post, not one hundred percent your entire structure but if i had to guess based off the post I would try this as my routes first..

```
$route['titles/titles/edit/(:any)'] = 'titles/titles/edit/$1';
$route['titles/titles/add'] = 'titles/titles/add';
$route['titles/titles'] = 'titles/titles';
$route['titles'] = 'titles/index';
```

Comment: I never once mentioned a model. If u notice it's module which is different.

Comment: bah, so I miss read.. does the answer help any based on the speculations of your original post despite the model/module thing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom routing in your configuration files ?

The general routing protocol used by codeigniter is like this:

```
domain.com/controller/methode/param1/param2/param3
```

This being said, your url

```
siteurl.com/kowmanger/titles/titles/edit/$id
```

corresponds to something like this :

```
class Kownmanger extends CI_Controller
{
    public function titles($titles, $action, $id)
    {

    }
}
```

In case you are using sub-folders in your controllers folder, what I have just said will change, Could you please tell us what's your directory structure ?

Comment: kowmanager is the project, titles is the module because I have modularized parts of my project, titles is the controller, and then id was just a variable I was trying to pass.

Comment: By module do you mean subfolder?